# IEnumerator function getting overwritten by newer function calls

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a door system I'm testing at the moment. It goes through a `IEnumerator` function, however if I open one door, then another quickly right after, the first door will stop at where it was and the second door will take priority. Any workarounds for this?

```
public IEnumerator Animthingy(GameObject Object)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(DoorOpen, Object.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position, 2f);

    anim.SetBool("IsOpen", true);
    anim.SetBool("Activated", true);
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(DoorClose, Object.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position, 2f);

    anim.Play("DoorOpen");
    anim.SetBool("Activated", false);
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);

    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(DoorOpen2, Object.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position, 2f);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(3f);
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(DoorClose, Object.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position, 2f);

    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1.5f);

    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(DoorClose2, Object.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position, 2f);
    
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    Debug.Log("closing");
    anim.Play("DoorClose");
    AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(DoorOpen, Object.transform.parent.gameObject.transform.position, 2f);
    yield break;
}
```

Door 1 opens, door 2 opens, door 1 doesn't close but door 2 does.

Comment: How do you use StartCoroutine?

Comment: `             StartCoroutine(Colorswitch(Object, false));`
withing some if statements on update and some input checks, the coroutine is called

Comment: Could you please post a [mcve]